# Writing EventHandlers to manage connections in C#

Tags: c#

```
 public class RSensor : IRSensor
 {
        public RSensorType SensorType { get; protected set; }


        public event EventHandler ConnectionLost;

        public void Configure(Stream input, Stream output, RSensorType type, ISensorReciever reciever)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


        public RSensor()
        {

        }
}
```

I have a class `RSensor` that has an EventHandler `ConnectionLost` which will inform me when the connection goes down.

I have another class `ConnectionManager` that somehow needs to handle when the connection goes down. I have created a dummy function `void HandleConnectionLost()`
in this class. How do I trigger this function when the `EventHandler ConnectionLost` from `RSensor` class is triggered.

```
public class ConnectionManager
{
        ActiveList m_ActiveList;
        Dictionary<IRionSensor, VSManager> m_ConnectionManager;

        class VehicleStreamManager
        {
            public IVehicle Vehicle { get; set;  }
            public NetworkStream AStream { get; set; }
            public NetworkStream BStream { get; set; }
        }

        ConnectionManager(ActiveExercise exercise)
        {
            m_ActiveList = exercise;
            m_ConnectionManager = new Dictionary<IRSensor, VehicleStreamManager>();
        }

        void Connect()
        {
            List<VehicleStreamManager> vsmList;
            VehicleStreamManager vsm;


            vsm = InitiateAVehicleConnections();

            m_ConnectionManager.Add(null, vsm);


            vsmList = InitiateBVehicleConnections();

            foreach(var item in vsmList)
            {
                RSensor fsensor = new RSensor();
                fsensor.Configure(item.AStream, item.BStream, RSensorType.RSensor_Both, null);
                m_ConnectionManager.Add(fsensor, item);
            }
        }

        void HandleConnectionLost()
        {
            //Do some stuff
        }


   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to redefine your `HandleConnectionLost` handler slightly, so that it conforms to an `EventHandler` signature:

```
void HandleConnectionLost(object sender, EventArgs args) 
{
  // Do stuff here
}
```

Then, in your `ConnectionManager` loop that instantiates sensors, you need to wire up the event handlers:

```
foreach(var item in vsmList)
{
    RSensor fsensor = new RSensor();
    fsensor.Configure(item.AStream, item.BStream, 
      RSensorType.RSensor_Both, null);
    fsensor.ConnectionLost += HandleConnectionLost;
    m_ConnectionManager.Add(fsensor, item);
}
```

This way, you handler will be triggered whenever one of the sensors loses the connection.

You are not showing the code that does this, but you said that `ConnectionLost` event *will inform me when the connection goes down*. I take this to mean that there is code present that raises the event already. If not, let me know and I'll extend the example.

However, the sensor must rely on some kind of external notification of the connection being lost - it will likely rely on a lower-level infrastructure.

Comment: Here the `object sender` is the sensor object ?

Comment: @liv2hak Yes. Sender would be the sensor.